# how to use jp3d in openjpeg

Tags: jpeg2000, openjpeg

Due to the needs of the project, I need to use jp3d to compress some 3D medical images(nii). I learned that https://www.openjpeg.org/ implements the functions of jp3d, but when I checked the usage documentation, I did not notice any description of using jp3d. How to use jp3d?

From this release interface: https://github.com/uclouvain/openjpeg/releases?page=1, I downloaded the windows version of the software and used opj_compress.exe for compression.

Comment: You have to set `BUILD_JP3D=ON` in cmake. Then it will appear to you `bin/jp3d/opj_jp3d_compress` and `bin/jp3d/opj_jp3d_decompress` binnaries.